# Scrapy/Python/MySQL: What is the best approach for saving additional item information in a separate table?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am crawling a website with Scrapy containing some kind of `listings` and store the new listings in a MySQL table. For each `listing` I want to add the `price` in a separate table (when it changes).

### My current approach

The `listings` table:

```
<id> | guid | title | body | created_at
-------------------------------------
```

The `listing_prices` table:

```
<id> | listing_id | price | created_at
------------------------------------
```

Using a `AddListingsToDatabase()` pipeline for saving new listings and afterwards using a `AddPricesToDatabase()` pipeline for saving new/updated prices to the database.

In the `AddPricesToDatabase()` I am querying the database to get all listings with prices. Then I check if the price has changed and add/update the price. Therefor I need the `listing.id`.

So far, this only works for listings which already were in the database before the current crawl.

### My problem

When I want to add new prices to the database, I need the `listing.id` (auto_increment) from the database. When I am querying the database in the `AddPricesToDatabase()` pipeline it doesn't yet find the listings newly added by the `AddListingsToDatabase()` pipeline.

### My questions

What is the best approach for saving additional information for a scraped `Item` in a separate table?

Comment: You defnitely need some more unique identifier to store. such as URL of the product specific page. Its unique product code (if any; provided on that URL)

Comment: The `guid` is the unique identifier from the current source page (A) and is stored in the `listing` table. The problem is, that if I later add other source sites (with the same listings) this `guid` from site A won't be unique anymore - as other sites might use the same `guid` for their listings.

Comment: Yes, that is why you need to store the full URL path for each listing page, in order to be able to differentiate

Comment: Okay - doing that in the `listings` table. But still having the problem how to access the `listing.id` for storing the price.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, instead of auto-incrementing your identifier, you could create a combined identifier, such as `website_id` + `listing_id` that would uniquely identify your record.

You can store this in a single column, or in two separate columns and create a combined key.

For example:

`websites` table:

```
<id> | website_url
------------------
```

`listings` table:

```
<id> | website_id | guid | title | body | created_at
----------------------------------------------------
```

`listing_prices` table:

```
<id> | website_id | listing_id | price | created_at
---------------------------------------------------
```

In the `listings` table, you would have to ensure that the combination of `id` and `website_id` is unique.